# How do I use an array as a parameter for a function?

Tags: arrays, processing, assertion

I'm having trouble with a task
I'm supposed to write a function which gets an int array as parameter and adds all numbers inside the array
The result should then be returned as an integer
with an array like

```
int [] foo = {  1,  2,  3};  // the result should be: 6
```

I currently have the following code:

```
    int [] foo = {  1,  2,  3};  // Expected results: 6
int [] bar = {-50, 25, 78};  // Expected results: 103
int [] foobar = {};          // Expected results: 0
void setup() {
  pro(foo[1]);
  
  }

int pro(int arr[] ) {
 int erg=0; 
  for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     
    erg+=arr[i];
    }
  println(erg);
  return erg;
  }
```

Also I'm supposed to use assertions to test my function with the stated arrays.
But it doesn't work obviously, that's why I'm here.
The language I'm using is Processing

Comment: "It doesn't work" meaning what exactly? What's the specific issue?

Comment: It says

The method pro(int[]) in the type sketch_210303b is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `pro()` an *array*? `pro(foo[1])` is just passing it a single integer. `foo[1]` is 2. What is `pro(2)` supposed to be?

Comment: @John Coleman yes exactly, it should be able to calculate the result of foo, bar and foobar. 
So resulting I somehow need to be able to fit any of those array into the function
the pro function is supposed to calcualte the sum of the array and the "pro" in the setup is where one should insert the array

Comment: If you know that you are supposed to pass `pro()` a whole array, why are you passing it a single integer? What is the `[1]` in `pro(foo[1])` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Berceuse it once stated that I need and int inside arr[]
If I remove the 1 it says 
the function "pro()" expects parameters like "pro(int[])

Comment: In the `setup` method of your example, call your method like this: `pro(foo);`. Have fun!

Comment: @laancelot 
Omg it was so simple....
Thanks a lot m8, sorry for not seeing it I'm still a complete beginner.

Comment: @Leo We all know your pain, pass on the knowledge when you'll be able to!